# Using FKs to find the shortest path between two columns in the database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm currently working on a project where the data graph is very confusing. For example if you want to find the region to which a contract will be applied, instead of just 
having a FK for the region in the Contract table, you will only have a FK of the agency who is in charge of monitoring the contract, then from that table you will link to the 
department of your company who is in charge of dealing with that agency, then from that department you will move toward the business unit ID, then from the Business Units table 
you will eventually find a FK to the region you're interested in.

This is a real pain, because in addition to this, the business logic is implemented in the database and it is an industry which is quite complicate.
So when developing, we are dealing with two complexities : finding our data, and understanding the business logic.

Understanding the data graph actually requires to have a very good understanding of the domain. I know and I agree that every developer should understand the domain on which he is working, 
but here it's a very a huge task. We are talking about a regulated industry, with a lot of specific rules.

And with the example I've given, you can see that even if you are working
on the Contract Creation module, you can't just say : well, I'll go ahead and study deeply the domain for that part, because when it comes to finding the region, you'll eventually need to know that you will find it at the other part of the data graph. 
And it was really just an example, the real entities are much less intuitive than that.

I had an idea yesterday. Since in SQL Server we have access to the schema of all the database, I would like to write a script that would take 2 arguments :

-The Table StartPoint's Name
-And the Column name we are after.

And it would return a "graph" of all the paths that are possible to access it.

Is it an easy task to do, and how would you go about it ? (I am not an SQL Server expert)

Comment: You cannot expect to find a valid answer without providing all the data you are working with, which you cant and wont do.

Comment: You may find creating `database diagram`s for all or part(s) of your database useful (assuming it's constrained correctly - the FK relationships will be drawn automatically for you - and that you have access to SQL Management Studio or equivalent).  BOL or Google or YouTube will be your friend [example](http://youtu.be/St4FQd-itu0)

Answer (score 1):

It would be a fairly large task for me to write this out, but if you create a recursive CTE, using sys.foreign_keys and sys.foreign_key_columns, you could accomplish this. I think this post, [Traverse through all foreign keys in database and generate a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606097/traverse-through-all-foreign-keys-in-database-and-generate-a-path) , or this one, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/66f379e1-32bc-44cb-bb48-93f42993ba23/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-order-in-which-you-need-to-perform-deletes-when-there-using-a?forum=transactsql , is close to what I'm picturing, and then just applying a WHERE filter.